# Nielsen & Chuang Exercise 4.34 "Measuring an operator"

Tags: circuit-construction, measurement, nielsen-and-chuang, matrix-representation

I need help with the exercise 4.34 from Nielsen & Chuang Book.

[image]

I am supposed to get a matrix corresponding to the circuit. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11730/showing-measurement-of-a-hermitian-unitary-operator-gives-final-states-as-eigenv/11731#11731

Comment: @Peter-Jan, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show that the circuit satisfies the problem's criteria like so:
[image]

From here: https://github.com/rehaanahmad2013/NielsenChuang-QuantumComputingSolutions

Comment: thank you so much! Could not find a solution by myself